# class_eval how to pass parameter to method

Tags: ruby

How do I pass the parameter name in the following case..the name is being is evaluated before being passed to class_eval

```
 
class Foo

end

Foo.class_eval %Q{
def hello(name)
 p "hello #{name}"
end
}
```

Sorry about not giving the entire scenario...
I just wanted to add a instance method dynamically to a class and that method should be able to take arguments...
the above code would not compile complaining that the name is not defined as local variable when executing in irb..

Thanks

Comment: Not sure what you're asking; you want to change the name of the parameter to `hello`? Oh, I get it--the answers are the easiest solution.

Comment: your question is barely coherent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The other answers are the "right" answer, but you could also just skip interpolating inside the `p` call:

```
Foo.class_eval %Q{
  def hello(name)
    p "hello \#{name}"
  end
}
```

I thought you wanted to change the actual parameter name (possibly useful for completion or when using Pry on dynamic methods), here assuming it's in a global, but could also be passed into a method doing the `class_eval`:

```
Foo.class_eval %Q{
  def hello(#{$argname})
    p "hello \#{$argname}"
  end
}
```

Comment: @coool The others do too ;) They're probably better answers, too; cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

Really simple:

```
Foo.class_eval do
    def hello(name)
        p "hello #{name}"
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try passing a block to `class_eval` instead of an array ([from this link](http://ilikestuffblog.com/2009/01/09/fun-with-rubys-instance_eval-and-class_eval/)):

```
class Foo
end

Foo.class_eval {
  def hello(name)
    p "hello #{name}"
  end
}
```

You then can call the instance method `hello` in the usual fashion:

```
boo = Foo.new
boo.hello("you")
```

which produces:

```
>> boo.hello("you")
"hello you"
=> nil
```

Comment: I wanted to pass a string/ create a new method out of string..anyway thanks for you answer

Answer (score 0):

```
class Foo
end

Foo.class_eval do
  define_method :hello do |name|
    p "hello #{name}"
  end
end

Foo.new.hello("coool") # => "hello coool"
```

Comment: ruby has some many ways of doing things...add dynamically methods...cheers

Comment: why did you use `define_method` instead of just `def` ? :)

Comment: Exactly for the same reason as #class_eval was used instead of class opening: just like that :-)